# Scala - Problem with URL encoding for POST request

Tags: scala, http, curl, post

I have a strange HTTP problem that works in `curl` but not when I'm using `HttpURLConnection` from `java.net` in my Scala script.

I have a curl command that looks like this:

```
curl --location 'https://some.url.com/api/endpoint' \
    --header 'Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=john.doe@example.com' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=abcdeg123456'
```

This command works and I get a valid response from the server.

Now I do the same thing in a scala script (simplified here for better reading):

```
val url = "https://some.url.com/api/endpoint"
val headerParams = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=john.doe@example.com&client_secret=abcdeg123456"
val postData = headerParams.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
val postDataLength = postData.length

val connection: HttpURLConnection = new URL(url).openConnection.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
connection.setDoOutput(true)
connection.setUseCaches(false)
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8")
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", postDataLength.toString)

// skipping the resource closing part for better reading
val outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream)
outputStream.write(postData)
val inputStream = connection.getInputStream

// print the result
println(
   scla.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
)
```

This Scala script also gives a valid response, the same as the curl command. So I know my script works.

Now I have a new user with a tag added to the email address and suddenly my scala script stopped working.

The new user is now `john.doe+api@example.com` with the `+api` tag added and the client id changed as well.

With the new curl command, it still works and I get a valid response.

```
curl --location 'https://some.url.com/api/endpoint' \
    --header 'Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=john.doe+api@example.com' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=123456abcdefg'
```

But if I amend my scala script:

```
...
val headerParams = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=john.doe+api@example.com&client_secret=123456abcdefg"
...
```

Then I suddenly get a `500` response for the server. But I know that it works in curl.

Do you have any idea if there could be something with the way I encode my header parameters in the Scala script? Or at least how I could better debug this.

Thanks,
Felix

Comment: You should probably URL-encode `headerParams` before converting it into bytes and writing it to the output stream.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, it did not work. But thanks for your help @stefanobaghino

I looked for a more modern library and I think I will introduce this to our code base. I will write a post on this below...

Comment: Could it be possible that you encoded the whole thing, including `=`s and `&`s, instead of encoding each key and value separately _and then_ put them together with `=`s and `&`s? It looks like that's what `requests` is doing: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala/blob/ac506a50267ede978061e62c2a4a3e41ad7f1264/requests/src/requests/Util.scala#L24-L27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a library that abstracts the problem away as mentioned in @Phoen's answer makes sense in many cases. If by any chance you can't use it (or simply prefer not to), the missing piece here was to URL-encode the keys and values passed to the server.

This is achieved using `java.net.URLEncoder` [in the library mentioned as a possible solution](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala/blob/ac506a50267ede978061e62c2a4a3e41ad7f1264/requests/src/requests/Util.scala#L24-L27) as follows:

```
def urlEncode(x: Iterable[(String, String)]) = {
  x.map{case (k, v) => URLEncoder.encode(k, "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(v, "UTF-8")}
      .mkString("&")
}
```

Passing the result of

```
urlEncode(
  Map(
    "client_id" -> "john.doe+api@example.com"
    "client_secret" -> "123456abcdefg"
  )
)
```

to the server should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into different libraries, especially for Scala where most of the heavy lifting happens under the hood.

I found this library from lihaoyi and that works for me pretty well.

Dependency: `"com.lihaoyi" %% "requests" % "0.8.0"`

```
val url = "https://some.url.com/api/endpoint"
val headerParams = Map(
   "client_id" -> "john.doe+api@example.com"
   "client_secret" -> "123456abcdefg"
)
val response = requests.post(url, headerParams)
println(response.text)
```

Comment: Should the call be `requests.post(url, data = headerParams)`? I'm trying to understand what the library does right that was missing from the original question. :)

Comment: I suspect this is the part that does the trick: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala/blob/master/requests/src/requests/Util.scala#L24-L27, which is called by the implicit conversion from `Iterable[(String, String)]` (of which `Map[String, String]` is a sub-type) https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala/blob/ac506a50267ede978061e62c2a4a3e41ad7f1264/requests/src/requests/Model.scala#L104-L112, which is ultimately called here https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala/blob/ac506a50267ede978061e62c2a4a3e41ad7f1264/requests/src/requests/Requester.scala#L253-L264

Comment: Oh yes, you are right @stefanobaghino!
I encoded the "=" as well and not just the parameters. Now it works.

But it is funny that it worked for the old user `john.doe@example.com` but not for the `john.doe+api@example.com`.

Coolcoolcool, now I don't need to introduce another library, thanks :)

Comment: I'm slightly surprised as well, since `@` looks like the kind of symbol that needs to be URL-encoded, but I'm not an expert. If you can, probably you should get in touch with the maintainer of the server, I don't think it should 500 on a badly-encoded string.

Comment: I already got in touch with them. I think they don't want to improve their error handling. ;D
Thanks for your help @stefanobaghino